# quartz cron expression help (daily trigger)

Tags: triggers, cron, quartz-scheduler

i want to run a cron trigger every 5th day starting from the 16th of every month.

so it should execute on every:
16th, 21st, 26th, 31st, 5th, 10th, 15th, 20th and so on

i tried "0 0 1 16/5 * ?" but this gets execute on 16th, 21st, 26th, 31st, 16th, 21st.... It skips anything between 1st and 15th.

Please help.
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "every 5th day"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this with a combination of [NthIncludedDayTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/NthIncludedDayTrigger.html) to select every 5th day, and [MonthlyCalendar](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/impl/calendar/MonthlyCalendar.html) to mask off the first 15 days of the month.